# Is there a way to attach lftp to a lftp process running another machine?

Tags: lftp

When you exit lftp it keeps running in the background and the `attach` command is used to attach lftp to that process once again if you need to but I'm wondering if there is a way to attach lftp to a lftp process running another machine to which you have ssh access? An example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do when provided with ssh access. Just do

```
ssh user@host "lftp -c attach"
```